# What data type I should preferably use for storing flag fields in sql server?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

What data type I should preferably use for storing flag fields in sql server, bit(if I have only 0,1 and null), tinyint, smallint or int for flags which cannot be accommodated into bit?  Does it effect my query performance?

Comment: Depends how many different values the flag can hold.  Less than 255 Tinyint will do it.  I dont think there will be any noticeable difference in performance.

Comment: Fred is correct. This is the better choice, and it leaves room to grow. SOme suggested a NULLable bit, but IMO, this is ambiguous.  A bit is 1 or 0. NULL BIT means not set, and is more of a hassle to code around. Yes, it can be used. Yes, there are special situations that require this.  But straight flags should use TINYINT.

Comment: @Graeme, If I have to select between tinyint, short or Int for flags which one to go with the performance perspective? Let Bit apart as it can store flags upto 0 and 1 only.

Comment: @Niraj - sorry to take so long to respond. "It depends" on how you are using the flag. If you are coordinating it with an enum in your code, then what matters is how many choices you embrace, and whether or not you combine them (true flags). Choose the minimum width that will serve the data. This can make querying a little klunky, if you have to parse out the values. In that case, you may feel that normalizing it (by using a related table) will be more helpful. Some want to use a bitmask. This can be tricky to code against--and validate. Throughput and processing time are key factors.

Comment: Take a look at this commentary. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/when-to-use-tinyint-over-int

Comment: @Graeme, Thanks for the link you provided, I got exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

Use Bit Datatype which is set to 1 if true or 0 ir False, much smaller and faster to query against Bit values Your column could be saved as 1 Byte if you have 8 or less Bit columns in your table and I think if you have more then 8 then SQL Server uses 2 Bytes Column , Which is A lot smaller than any other options you might have, tinyint, smallint and int all requires more space then a bit column and querying a bigger datatype means more time to query the data. 
**My Suggestion**
My Suggestion would be to use Bit Column as it requires less space to store it and queries can perform much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I am prety much ok with using Bit data type for flags, but I want to know the suitable data type in case if flag values are bigger and cannot be accommodated into a bit? and I also want to know why(related to query performance). e.g. I have 10 different flag values then in that case which data type I should use and why?

Comment: The problem with bits is of course that you need a schema change any time you want a new flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
bit
```

its a boolean, so its only 1 or 0, and doesn't require a whole byte to store. Plus you can just make it nullable on the table design.

Comment: I have edited my question to clear your confusion, I want to know the suggestion in case if flag values are bigger than can be accommodated into a bit? and I also want to know why(related to query performance).

Comment: Right, so you don't want a BIT. Use a char(1) instead??

Comment: Being a stickler here: the SQL Server `bit` data type is not a boolean. Simplest way to illustrate this is `SELECT 'hmm' WHERE Cast(1 As bit)`. You will receive an error because the where clause doesn't evaluate. If it were a true boolean then you would not need to add an equals operator for this to compile.

Comment: @Rich, will char be faster than tinyint or short or int with the performance perspective when storing numeric flag values?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer for what I was looking, we should consider using smallest data type sufficient enough to store flag values required. This is with respect to the performance of database as storage size is not a big concern these days.

have a look at this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4968/when-to-use-tinyint-over-int) for more insights.

As per this link think about how resources other than disk space are used, think about buffer pool and storage bandwidth. At the extreme end, CPU cache and memory bus bandwidth, and also about how SQL Server works.